# Thoughts on reusing a controller for different routes

Tags: ember.js

I have several objects which are behaving very similarly. I would like to provide a base implementation for the controllers related to those objects, and then `extend` those controllers to slightly customize the behaviour. I am doing something like this:

```
App.BaseIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    ...
});
```

And now I would use the base controller to define my real object controller:

```
App.AgentsIndexController = App.BaseIndexController.extend({
    ....
});
```

I have two questions:

1. Are there any general comments discouraging this kind of reuse?
2. Is the `extend` mechanism the right way to reuse a generic controller implementation, ensuring that no state data will "leak" between controllers extending the same base controller?

Comment: I think it's better to define a `Ember.Mixin` for your basical behaviour and use it like this `App.AgentsIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(BaseIndexControllerMixin, {});`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as you've suggested, but note that any properties defined in App.BaseIndexController will leak over if they've been initiated ([check this out](http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2012/03/06/understanding-ember-object/) for a common mistake)

`Mixins` can also work well, since they're more reusable. Ember uses `Mixins` a lot internally so you can't go wrong with that approach.